# Does modern IDE compile source code instantly and continueously?

Tags: ide

Modern IDE such as Visual Studio and Android Studio can highlight syntax errors, spot out typos in variable and method names, highlight the variables that are not declared etc.

So are these IDE compile the source code instantly and continueously? If yes, why the actual compile process is often much slower than highlighting errors?

Comment: Thats because the one you are talking about is called parsing and the other is compiling. So i am not aware of any fact that IDES compile ad-hoc. Bit what they do is a parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Visual Studio** doesn't compile when it spots syntactic and semantic/logical errors, but it can detect these errors by performing the **"lexical analysis"** and **"syntactical analysis"** steps of compiling code that other IDEs might take while compiling **without compiling** because it has a built-in functionality for that. When you click "**Build**", that's when the source code is compiled. Compiling takes longer because because the compiler does not only go about indicating errors, but also converts your source code into assembly language and then machine code (complicated process whose speed depends on many factors). Also, the compiler sets aside memory on the heap and call stack. These processes force the compilation phase to take longer than just pointing out errors.